# How to skip columns in “List from a range” Criteria?

Tags: validation, google-sheets

Is it possible to create a "List from a range" Data Validation rule in Google Sheets where the range skips columns?

**For example:**

Cells A6:A11 is limited to the range A1:B3. Cells B6:B11 is limited to the range A1:A3 AND C1:C3 (skips column B).

Creating a Data Validation rule for cells A6:A11 is trivial as I simply need to create a Criteria of "List from a range = A1:B3".

However, creating the Data Validation rule for cells B6:B11 is not so intuitive since Google Sheets does not allow me to create a Criteria using the syntax "List from a range = A1:A3, C1:C3".

Does the "List from a range" Criteria support a syntax that allows us to skip columns within a range?

[image]

*Note: I currently have a work around for this where I defined an array formula in D1 = =ArrayFormula(if({1,""},A1:A3,C1:C3)) and then use D1:E3 as the Data Validation range. But this is a hacky solution and I'm hoping there is a better way to accomplish my goal.*

Comment: Sorry, but I believe that you cannot skip a column in "List from a range" Criteria, not even with `Custom formula` to attempt to combine the columns into one. The only workaround is to use a helper column which is a combination of the columns you need, as you already used.

Well you can always use `D1={A1:A3;C1:C3}` and then use `D:D` for the validation range. At least, I think the formula is ... less hacky ? And  you can always hide the helper column,.. in which case just place it at ZZ or something. No one will ever notice it's missing =))

Comment: Refer my solution for this exact same question on [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120947/how-to-skip-columns-in-list-from-a-range-criteria/).

Comment: Of course, it can be done! See my answer for a how-to...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `{ }` to create a combination of columns or rows that will result in some sort of virtual table on-the-fly.

Example:

Assuming you have a spreadsheet with `Name`, `Age`, `Gender`, `Phone` and `Address` in `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`, and you want to skip the `Gender` (column `C`) while using the `UNIQUE` statement, you can use something like this.

Put in `G1` the following formula:

`=UNIQUE({A1:B, D1:E})`

From the cell `G1`, the spreadsheet will populate the columns `G`, `H`, `I` and `J` with unique combinations of `A`, `B`, `D` and `E`, excluding the column `C` (`Gender`).

The same application of a combined range can be used in any formula and also you can combine multiple different ranges, including cross Spreadsheets and Files.

It is a very useful trick if you need to combine pieces of multiple spreadsheets for data visualization or reports. However, always remember you cannot manipulate the displayed data. You can still search through it, format it, etc., but you cannot change it. On the other hand, it will auto-update always if the data source gets updated, which is very useful.

Note: Try it with `LOOKUP`, `VLOOPUP` or `HLOOKUP`.